# Connecting to Perforce Personal Server on Lan

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have created a Personal Server using the P4V "Helix Client" on my Windows 10 workstation at home.

[image]

I would like to be able to connect to this server from my laptop on the LAN so that I can pull from it. (To make sure that everything that is required for the project is correctly in the repository, and testing)

Should I be able to connect to this server using the workstations IP address and port 1666?

Is there an additional step I need to take to "serve" the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "personal server" doesn't listen on the network by default (the client spawns a short-lived server process in place each time it runs a command).

To convert your personal server into a shared server, install the Perforce service (this'll be part of the server installer on Windows) and set its server root directory to match the path you gave your personal server.

Alternatively, you can go to a command prompt and run:

```
p4d -r Z:\Core\.p4root -p 1666
```

but that server will only be up and listening for as long as that command prompt is open, whereas the service (p4s.exe) will run in the background.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Looks like i need a diffrent installer for p4D and s. I will check that out now.

Comment: Also, I was just reading about p4 zip which might just do what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

We need to provide "localhost:1666" as the server which means that (the same as the IP address 127.0.0.1). It will only work for you and not other machines.

Open the tab "Initialize New Personel Server" Tab and then specify your server location.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, Are you saying that if I specify localhost instead of the file it will serve the repository so my laptop can see it? The repo is curretly working fine on the localhost, I am having trouble connecting to it from another computer.

Comment: In that case, remove "localhost:1666" and try something as "ip of the server :1666", something as "192.168.171.12:1666"